# Saving value in a different variable every time it loops through an array

Tags: php, arrays, range

I have a large list Having similar headings i've exploded those two into arrays. I want to insert the the data under same heading through splice and get one big arrray example :

```
Array1 (           Array2(           Result Array(
[0]Heading1           [0]Heading1             [0]Heading1  )  
[1]data1               [1]data1               [1]data1
[2]data1               [2]Heading2            [2]data1
[3]data1               [3]data2               [3]data1
[4]Heading2            [4]data2               [4]data1
[5]data2               [5]data2  )            [5]Heading2
[6]data2                                      [6]data2
[7]data2                                      [7]data2
[8]data2                                      [8]data2
[9]data2                                      [9]data2
)                                             [10]data2
                                              [11]data2
                                              [12]data2
                                              [13]data2 )
```

Now i have matched the heading values and want to get the range on index in between matching values this is what i have tried :

```
<?php

$original = array( '1','f','g','h','2','m','n','o','p', '3', '4', '5' );
$Test = array('1','a','b','c','d','e','2','i','j','k','l');
foreach ($original as $key1 => $value1) {   
    foreach ($Test as $key2 => $value2) {
                
                if($value1 == $value2 ){

                        if(isset($firsttime)){}else{$firsttime = ($key1+1);} 
                        if(isset($secondtime)){}else{$secondtime = ($key1-1);} 
                }
            }       
 }
 
 foreach(range(firsttime,secondtime) as $key){
    echo $original[$key];
   }
 echo $firsttime.'<br>';
 echo $secondtime.'<br>';
?>
```

The first value matches at index 0 so i am getting value 1 and -1 the value i want is
1 and 3

Comment: What is the original source of the data, this looks over complicated and might be easier solved by building a different start set of arrays.

Comment: google sheet data i've joined the column with , seperator and exploded it into an array .
The sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XrQiNJzQckUdoeR6vhegoXFDpECSzqYtTMIyGGuNwVI/edit#gid=0

Comment: Can there be headings in the second array, that are not in the first one? And if so, how exactly do you want to handle those? Discard them, append them at the very end?

Comment: If all headings from the second array are guaranteed to be in the first one as well, then I would simply group the data by using the heading content as key first (assuming, the headings are unique), and then flatten the resulting array again afterwards. Example: https://3v4l.org/4v7rV I am using `is_numeric` here to "identify" the headings in your example data, you will need to replace that with whatever is appropriate for your actual data. The headings from the first array are inserted into the helper array, those from the second are not (because we don't want them repeated in the result.)

Comment: The values in the second array are guaranteed to be in the first one ill try this
The headings in acual data are city names

Comment: Can i match the match the if condition with an array of headings

Answer (score 0):

I had this list of certifications and institutes in two columns of a google sheet :https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XrQiNJzQckUdoeR6vhegoXFDpECSzqYtTMIyGGuNwVI/edit#gid=0

I had to parse this data with the Qualifications and Associations falling under the same headings and value from each cell separated by a comma.
First I added same headings to the second column manually and then used =JOIN (Google Sheet Formula) to get a single big string (values separated by comma) and exploded the string from both columns into two separate arrays.
Below are two static arrays that i used for testing, The values from
$original will be fed into $test.

```
$original = array( 'Hello','f','g','h','Hello2','m','n','o','p','Hello3','s','t','Hello4','x','y','z','Hello5','3','4','5','Hello6' );
$Test= array('Hello','a','b','c','d','e','Hello2','i','j','k','l','Hello3','q','r','Hello4','u','v','w','Hello5','1','2','Hello6');
$index = array();
$index1 = array();
$index2 = array();


foreach ($original as $key1 => $value1) {   
    foreach ($Test as $key2 => $value2) {

        if($value1 == $value2 ) :

            array_push($index,$key1);
            array_push($index1,$key1);
            array_push($index2,$key2);
        }
    }                   
}

foreach($index as $key => $numb){
    if($key % 2 == 0){
        $index[$key] = ($numb + 1);
    }
    else{
        $index[$key] = ($numb - 1);
    }
}
foreach($index1 as $key => $numb){
    if($key % 2 == 0){
        $index1[$key] = ($numb - 1);
    }
    else{
        $index1[$key] = ($numb + 1);
    }
}

$indexf  = array_merge($index,$index1);
sort($indexf);

array_shift($indexf);

array_pop($indexf);

array_shift($index2);

$next = array();
$new = array();
$i = 0 ;
$count = count($indexf);
$countf = ($count / 2);

for($p=0;$p < $countf;$p++) { 

    $zucc = range($indexf[$i], $indexf[($i + 1)]);

    foreach($zucc as $keye => $value )
    {                                               

        if((count($zucc)-1) == ($keye)){

            foreach($zucc as $key => $val){

                $zucc[$key]=$original[$val];

                array_push($new, $val);
            }

            array_push($next,count($new));
            if($p==0){
                $honka = count($new);
                array_splice($Test,($index2[$p]),0,$zucc);
            }
            else{   
                array_splice($Test,($index2[$p]+$next[($p-1)]),0,$zucc);
            }

        }                       
    }

    $i=($i+2);
}



print_r($Test);
```

I figured it out!
prolly there is an easier way to do this :3
but i got my result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
    [4] => d
    [5] => e
    [6] => f
    [7] => g
    [8] => h
    [9] => Hello2
    [10] => i
    [11] => j
    [12] => k
    [13] => l
    [14] => m
    [15] => n
    [16] => o
    [17] => p
    [18] => Hello3
    [19] => q
    [20] => r
    [21] => s
    [22] => t
    [23] => Hello4
    [24] => u
    [25] => v
    [26] => w
    [27] => x
    [28] => y
    [29] => z
    [30] => Hello5
    [31] => 1
    [32] => 2
    [33] => 3
    [34] => 4
    [35] => 5
    [36] => Hello6
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).